# Zapatec Calendar Week Start - Thursday

Tags: javascript, calendar, dhtml

One of our websites uses an old DHTML widget called Zapatec.
It has a fairly straightforward setup and works as expected on my local environment and for other users.
The week starts on a Monday as it has been setup.

For one of our users though, their widget always starts on a Thursday. I've been racking my brain, wondering what it could be. Could it be their browser overriding the settings?

```
   Zapatec.Calendar.setup({
    firstDay          : 1,
    weekNumbers       : true,
    showOthers        : true,
    showsTime         : false,
    step              : 2,
    range             : [anoinicio, 2999.12],
    electric          : false,
    singleClick       : true,
    inputField        : inputC,
    button            : botonC,
    //ifFormat          : "%d/%m/%Y",
    ifFormat          : formato_fecha,
    daFormat          : "%Y/%m/%d",
    align             : "Br",
    displayArea       : false,
    dateText          : false,
      cache :true
  });
```

This is my code for the calendar setup. First day is set to 1 or Monday. It is in .cfm or Coldfusion file.

How it looks for me:

[image: How it looks for me]

How it looks for our user:

[image: How it looks on the user's pc]

Please ignore the week numbers in the first picture, I just added it.

Any assistance on this would be appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: What has this got to do with ColdFusion or CFML?

Comment: The `CFM` file is like `PHP` or other server-side language. It just spits out HTML, JS, and/or CSS. What is the other user's time zone? What browser are they using? I see a lot of issues like this based on browser settings alone. Depending on how many people are affected, you might need to replace the calendar widget with something more modern.

Comment: Adam, context I suppose. Apologies if that's not how it works here.
The page is wrapped in a .CFM file and runs on ColdFusion 9. So does the entire website.

@Adrian, thank you. Your comment helped, noticed it happens on Chrome but not Edge. Reckon it's got something to do with the browser ISO date settings.